# Is it possible to detect if a user has liked a facebook page from within a page tab without auth dialog?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've be sifting through different approaches on how to use the FB javascript api to check if a user has liked a page or not and show different page tab content depending on that.

I have seen an example of a product page that uses a page tab that shows different content for users liking or not liking the product, yet this (showing of different content) does not in itself require a popup requesting app access. From the examples found on SO I can make the FB.getLoginStatus request to get me the information I need, but not without sending the user to a login/dialog requesting permissions for the particular page app.

How can this (detecting page like) be done without a request for app access rights?

-

From all the examples I gather, I found it mandatory to request the app access rights, but here is an example where the content of the tab changes if you like/unlike, yet that in itself does not require an app access rights request: http://www.facebook.com/HifiStudioSuomi/app_514442371917093 (sorry if this link might not be available in the future - it's the one app that got me wondering how to do this :/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s done via the `signed_request` parameter, that get’s POSTed to page tab apps on initial load into the iframe.

But, since it’s POSTed, you have no access to it via JavaScript – so you will have to use some kind of server-side technique if you want to access this info.

Comment: Great, thanks! I used the `parse_signed_request` method from the api page about signed requests (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) in the php that prints the page tab and can grab the liked or not value from there.